# Is there any action I could do with POST, but not with GET?

Tags: html, http, post, get

I know differences and advantages of each command, my question is could I replace POST requests with GET everywhere? And which these commands calls by default while sending request from html form?

Comment: GET is the default method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could I replace POST requests with GET everywhere

No (and it would be a terrible idea to try).

Things that a form can do with POST that you can't do with GET include:

- Sending *lots* of data
- Sending files

There are other things that would simply be stupid to do with GET.

---

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method :

> The method and formmethod content attributes are enumerated attributes
>   with the following keywords and states:
>
> The keyword get, mapping to the state GET, indicating the HTTP GET
>   method. The keyword post, mapping to the state POST, indicating the
>   HTTP POST method. The invalid value default for these attributes is
>   the GET state. (There is no missing value default.)

Answer (score 0):

When using GET to transfer data from the client to the server, the data is added to the URL, there is not BODY of the request. There is usually a limit on how long a URL can be, in the old days this was 1024 characters but that really depends on the server software and server middleware and even the browser.

This means if you want to transfer loads or data or upload a file to the server, you can not do it with GET.